# RabbitMQ clustering mirrored queue behaviour

Tags: java, cluster-computing, rabbitmq, amqp

I am using RabbitMQ clustering. My queues are in "across all nodes" and "durable" state. But, when I kill master node(with 1000 messages in queue, for example), my slave node  continue working, but in queue I can see only 0 or small number of mesages.
Is it bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you declare the queue as HA?

E.g

Map args = new HashMap();
args.put("x-ha-policy", "all");
channel.queueDeclare("myqueue", false, false, false, args);

Comment: Yes, my queue parameters are HA and D